# Linux Debian 9 With Bind 9 DNS

Tags: bind9

**System:** I have 2 Debian 9 clean installs with Bind9 on both.

**Problem:** I am not sure if this is a issue or not but what is happening is ns2 is being queried before ns1.

**Domain:** intelacyber.com

**Question:** Is this normal and if not how can I fix this?

*If you need any other information please just let me know, thank you!*

Answer (score 0):

In this situation the problem was that I had a A record type that pointed to the ip address of ns1 in the ns1 record but not the ns2 record.